# aws api-gateway resource/paths seperation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

how to design cloud-formation templating for the scenario where we have an api-gateway and multiple associated proxy lambdas as resources/paths in multiple git repositories

when contacted the aws support, they mentioned it is recommended using 1 stack template for each api gateway, thereby the stack template can act as single source of truth and any changes to the API should be deployed using the define template only

in my scenario, the lambdas that attach as paths to the api-gateway are separated out into multiple repositories

eg:
{api-gateway}/accounts/profile -> points to accountsLambda in one repository
{api-gateway}/accounts/preferences -> points to preferencesLambda in an other repository

Comment: Are you using SAM or any other framework to deploy de Lambda functions?

Comment: initially tried with SAM and then shifted to plain cfn

Comment: Do you have the option to use Terraform?